# davfs2 keep files cached longer

Tags: linux, webdav, davfs2

I'm using `davfs2` to sync with my box.com account and I'm trying to play with the cache settings to get more Dropbox-like functionality.

I've noticed that after I don't open a file for a little while it gets removed from the cache. I've set my cache size to 2GB and my account only has 700MB of data. The functionality I'm trying to achieve is to basically keep files in the cache until it's full.

I realize that I could probably keep the files open in the background, but I'm wondering if there's a clean way to accomplish this.

Here's my `davfs2.conf`:

```
use_locks 0
cache_size 2048
file_refresh 5
```

I'm not so sure I want to play with `dir_refresh` since I definitely want to detect updated files (or am I understanding this option poorly?).